# Swappign two lines by their string at the same time java

Tags: java, string, list, swap

I'm trying to swap two names in a list with each other. I have used the code below but I am wondering if there is a way to swap them at the same time because it is making them both the same name. Is there another method I can use that will swap the two names at the same time? Thanks

```
      String searchOne = challengerName;
      String replacementOne = defenderName;

      String searchTwo = defenderName;
      String replacementTwo = swapperName;
      list.replaceAll(s -> s.contains(searchOne) ? replacementOne : s);
      list.replaceAll(s -> s.contains(searchTwo) ? replacementTwo : s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle both conditions at the same time.

```
        list.replaceAll(s -> s.contains(searchOne) ? replacementOne
                        : s.contains(searchTwo) ? replacementTwo : s );
```